# Expressing a connection of a vector bundle at a point

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, connections

Let $P\to X$ be a rank $n$ vector bundle with a metric over a smooth manifold $X$, and let $\nabla$ be a connection on $P$ that is compatible with the metric. Fix a point $x\in X$. Then is it true that we can choose an orthonormal basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $P_x$ so that $\nabla=\sum_k \nabla_{e_k}\otimes de_k$ at $x$? I am reading Morgan's book on Seiberg-Witten theory, and in the proof of Proposition 5.1.5, the writer chooses such a basis, but I can't see how this can be done.

Comment: Your statement makes no sense, as it confuses an orthonormal frame for $P$ with an orthonormal frame for $X$. Moreover, please say what $de_k$ is supposed to mean. See the comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the $\{e_i\}$ are a frame for the tangent bundle, as this is the only way in which the expression $\nabla_{e_i}$ could make sense. The connection $1$-form $A$ is defined by $\nabla e_i=\sum e_j\otimes A^j_i$. The connection coefficients $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ are defined by $\nabla_{e_j}e_i=\sum\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k$. We want a basis such that $\nabla e_i=\sum_j\nabla_{e_j}e_i\otimes \theta^j$, denoting by $\theta^j$ the coframe. Using the above definitions, this amounts to
$$\nabla e_i=\sum_j(\sum_k\Gamma^k_{ij}e_k)\otimes\theta^j=\sum_ke_k\otimes(\sum_j\Gamma^k_{ij}\theta^j)$$
This means that we want a basis so that the connection $1$-form is related to the connection coefficients via $$A^j_i=\sum_k\Gamma^j_{ki}\theta^k$$
This is the relation between the connection $1$-form and the connection coefficients, for a metric connection (e.g. on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form#Example:_the_Levi-Civita_connection ). So it should indeed be possible to find such a frame.

Comment: What does $\theta^j = de_j$ even mean?

Comment: Notation for the coframe associated to the frame $e_j$ which is used on wikipedia.

Comment: But this is an arbitrary vector bundle, not the tangent bundle. You’re reading things on Wikipedia that do not apply.

Comment: Surely, the fact that we have the expression $\nabla_{e_i}$ appearing in the OP means that the $\{e_i\}$ are in fact a frame for the tangent bundle, not for an arbitrary vector bundle?

Comment: No, the OP says explicitly that they're an orthonormal frame for $P_x$. I think you need to read questions more carefully.

Comment: How can the expression $\nabla_{e_i}$ make sense if $e_i$ is a section of anything but the tangent bundle?

Comment: Yeah, you're right that the original question is full of nonsense, too. I should have commented on the OP. But in your case, writing $de_j$ just is wrong, anyhow. The $\theta^j$ are the dual coframe corresponding to the orthonormal frame $e_1,\dots,e_n$. So, let's use $s_1,\dots,s_m$ for our frame for $P$ (without $m=n$). Then $\nabla s_i = \sum s_j\otimes A_i^j$, as you said, and $A_i^j = \sum \Gamma^j_{ik}\theta^k$.

Comment: You are right, the expression $de_j$ is wrong, I see what you mean now. I'll edit my answer to reflect your comment. I just read it in my head as $dx_j$.